# return source nodes of a directed graph

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

A source in a directed graph is a node that has no edges going into it. Give a linear-time algorithm
that takes as input a directed graph in adjacency list format, and outputs all of its sources.

solution:

Finding the sources of a directed graph.
We will keep an array in[u] which holds the indegree (number of incoming edges) of each node. For a
source, this value is zero.

```
function sources(G)
Input: Directed graph G = (V,E)
Output: A list of G's source nodes
for all u ∈ V : in[u] = 0
for all u ∈ V :
    for all edges (u,w) ∈ E:
      in[w] = in[w] + 1

L = empty linked list
for all u ∈ V :
    if in[u] is 0: add u to L
return L
```

the thing i particularly do not understand about the code above is the innermost for loop in the first code block what exactly does in[w] = in[w]+1 mean? i think it means its counting the indegrees of each node, but how exactly it's doing that i cannot picture it, can someone please help me visualize this aspect

Comment: It is looping over all edges u->w and incrementing the indegree for w node. What don't you understand?

Comment: why specifically the w node and not u as well? how does that work?

Comment: The edge is a directed edge from u to w. We want to count the number of incoming edges to the nodes. The node with zero 'incoming' edges is our source node.

Comment: The indentation in your pseudo code is misleading. The second `for all u ∈ V` loop is not nested into the first.

Answer (score 4):

`in[w] = in[w] + 1` increases the number of edges going into `w`.

**Maybe an example will help:**

Consider a simple graph:

```
a ---> b
```

The adjacency list representation is:

```
a: {b}
b: {}
```

Now the algorithm will loop through all vertices.

For `a`, it will loop over the edge `(a,b)` and increase `b`'s count.

For `b`, there are no edges.

Now `a`'s count is still zero, thus it is a source vertex.